# Adding Parse to existing Application

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, appdelegate

I'm new to Parse and working to add it to an existing application. I went through the Parse tutorial, but I have been unsuccessful for an existing app (succeeded for a new app).

In MSAppDelegate.m:

```
MSJournalerDoc *bug0 = [[MSJournalerDoc alloc] initWithTitle:@"Marcus" rating:4 thumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"MarcusThumb.jpg"] fullImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Marcus.jpg"]];
NSMutableArray *bugs = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:bug0, nil];
```

This is the current setup (prior to Parse).

I tried to add parse to this equation:

```
MSJournalerDoc *bug0 = [[MSJournalerDoc alloc] initWithTitle:@"Marcus" rating:4 thumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"MarcusThumb.jpg"] fullImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Marcus.jpg"]];
NSMutableArray *bugs = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:bug0, nil];
[bug0 saveInBackground];
```

But I get the error "No visible @interface for "MSJournalerDoc" declares the selector 'saveInBackground'

I have the correct imports on the MSAppDelegate.m file as well as the MSJournalerDoc.m

What am I doing wrong? thanks

MSJournalDoc.m looks like this:

```
- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString*)title rating:(float)rating thumbImage:(UIImage *)thumbImage fullImage:(UIImage *)fullImage {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        self.data = [[MSJournalerData alloc] initWithTitle:title rating:rating];
        self.thumbImage = thumbImage;
        self.fullImage = fullImage;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: what is `MSJournalerDoc`? Probably, you should save PFObjects in background

Answer (score 1):

You cannot just save any arbitrary object to Parse directly. Check here to see what type of objects are supported:
https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#objects-types/iOS

Without knowing exactly what `MSJournalerDoc` is, it is difficult to advise on how you should handle this situation, but one solution is to map your `MSJournalerDoc` to a parse object. You can use this object mapper whenever you need to create an `MSJournalerDoc` from Parse, or when you need to save it.

Answer (score -1):

In your `MSJournalerDoc.h` file, you need to declare a function header that looks like this:

```
- (void)saveInBackground;
```

And you will need to implement this method in `MSJournalerDoc.m`.